# Conditioning on correlated random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ be i.i.d. exponential random variables.

\begin{align}
Z_1 &= X_1 - \epsilon_1 X_2 - \epsilon_2 X_3 \\
Z_2 &= X_1 - \epsilon_2 X_2 - \epsilon_1 X_3
\end{align}

where $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are small positive numbers. Hence $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are positively correlated random variables.

My intuition says that $\Pr\{Z_1\leq w \mid Z_2 \leq w\}  \geq \Pr\{Z_1 \leq w\}$. But how to prove it?